# Microsoft Graph: reportRoot: getMailboxUsageDetail. Filter on lastActivityDate property?

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, outlook-restapi

My use case is to get all mailboxes which are not being used actively. So that we can take appropriate action like removing O365 license and free up licenses.

For this, I am using the graph API [getMailboxUsageDetail](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/docs/api-reference/v1.0/api/reportroot_getmailboxusagedetail)

I am trying to filter out based on lastActivityDate property but not getting expected result. I have 2 questions on this.

1. Is this the correct way to find all not actively used mailboxes? If not, please let me know what is the correct way?
2. If yes, is this filter property supported?